# Accessing jQuery object in remote js file using onclick HTML attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have put the following code is a remote js file

```
//in remote file invoice-add.js
(function($){

    $.invoicepage = function(options){

           var invoice = {

                //object method details inserted here
                addInvoiceItem: function (name, cost, price){}
           };

           return invoice;
    };
})(jQuery);
```

and Im trying to access it from the main HTML file like

```
<script src="path/to/invoice-add.js"></script>

$(function(){

    var inv = $.invoicepage();
});
```

I am trying to access the addInvoiceItem method inside the invoicepage object using an onclick attribute in an HTML tag as follows:

```
<a onclick="$(this).inv.addInvoiceItem('Item', 'USD 1,000.00', '1000')">Add New item</a>
```

But on running it I get the error

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addInvoiceItem' of
>   undefined

What Im I doing wrong here??

Comment: pass the element selector directly in place of 'this'

Comment: `var inv = ...` has nothing to do with `$(this).inv`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`this` is pointing to the dom element..
Also the variable should be inside $ object.
look at this fiddle..
https://jsfiddle.net/m0m1jnhk/5/